# Unable to figure out which data structure to use for efficiency

Tags: python, tree

I come from C background currently learning Python. My task is to create a general tree. The input to the program is in two passes. In the first pass I must collect the identity, name, role and dept of a person. In the second pass I get to know the parent of a node, the manager. So I must store the values transiently. In C I would typically use an array of structs or a linked list depending on the availability of the size information. But I am lost here in Python, not even sure if what I am doing is okay let alone efficient.

Thanks in advance,
Preeti.

```
if __name__ == "__main__": 
  # Have successfully created the tree and added nodes by hardcoding values as shown below in commented code
  # create_tree = Tree()
  # Tree.add_node(42, "Stephen", "Time Cone Radiation", "Black Hole")

  # But unable to figure out how to store transient info and use it later to create the tree. 
  num = 8
  list = []
  backup_num = num
  while num:
    id, name, role, dept = raw_input().split()
    num -= 1
    list.append((id, name, role, dept))

  while backup_num:
    id, parent = raw_input().split()
    backup_num -= 1
    #For an id in the list above locate it, and call add_node.
    # But not sure how and what is an efficient way.
```

Comment: Have you tried dictionary? I guess list of dictionary will suit you best here.

Comment: I can use id as the key to dictionary but I am struggling with parsing the input and store id as an integer wrt to the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a fare idea. Hope this helps.

```
class Tree():
    def __init__(self):
        self.length = 0
        self.data = {}

    def add_node(self, nodeid, name, role, dept):
        obj = {}
        obj["child"] = {"left": None, "right": None}
        obj["parent_id"] = None
        obj["name"] = name
        obj["role"] = role
        obj["dept"] = dept

        self.data[nodeid] = obj
        self.length += 1
        return True

    # which_one : Left or Right
    def update_child_id(self, which_one, nodeid_parent, nodeid_child):
        self.data[nodeid_parent]["child"][which_one] = nodeid_child
        return True

    def update_parent(self, nodeid, parent_id):
        self.data[nodeid]["parent_id"] = parent_id
        return True

    def display_node(self, nodeid):
        obj = self.data[nodeid]
        print("Node:", nodeid)
        print("Parent:", obj["parent_id"], ", Name:", obj["name"], ", Role: ", obj["role"], ", Dept: ", obj["dept"])

    def display_child(self, nodeid):
        print(self.data[nodeid]["child"].items())


# Main 
test = Tree()

# Get the identity and then add here
node_id, name, role, dept = [42, "Stephen", "Time Cone Radiation", "Black Hole"]
test.add_node(node_id, name, role, dept)

# Get the parent id and add here
parent_id, parent = [6, "James"]
test.update_parent(node_id, parent_id)

test.display_node(42)
test.display_child(42)
```